# best approach to update panel of data with jquery from mysql source - json?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, xml, json

My question falls into the category "what's the best way to?" "how would you do this?".

I've built a page that sources data from a mysql database which is displayed in a table with row and column headings. The html for the table is built in php and jquery loads a the built table with the result of the php file using .html()

This works. I have an index at the top which when the user clicks on it the respective 'record' is loaded into the data table. I do this by re-creating the table in php (as with the initial build), fade out the existing table, make an html call, fadein the panel. Again this all works fine

However the solution isn't very elegant and i'm looking for a way to retain the row and column headings and then just update the table values. I'm struggling to find a solution for this (or get my head around the steps required.

What is a good solution for this. The data resides in a mysql database so php will be used to pull the data. Should I be looking to convert the data to an xml/json feed. I;ve created an xml file before with php but not sure if this is the right way and not sure how I can just update the values and want to avoid a page reload hence jquery.

Linked to this also is when the data is updated, a series of images are also updated tha relate to the pulled record.

Any help being pointed in the right direction appreciated

Thanks

update: there is in effect only one mysql that the data is retrieved from

Update: as suggested in the answer below I'm going to try the Json approach. - Now to learn about getJson!!!

Thanks

Comment: How many different tables are there, and how big are they? Could you load each one into json and just reload that table with jquery when you need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already gave the answer in the question, but I may point you to the right direction. 
Fastest way is to make calls via jquery to an php file which delivers you the data as a json object. Then you may parse through the information and update your table and images as stated in the question. If you need further help in how to create a json object with php you may look at (your data has to be within an array - which is correct if you are using mysql_fetch_assoc for calling the data from Mysql): http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

You can loop through the result of the mysql query yourself, and then create an JSON String as you may need it from your jquery call.

XML is also an option, but there is some tiny overhead needed to have an valid xml document - but if you are more experienced in using XML this may be the way to go - although JSON is the modern web-technology.

To retain the Headings, just dont change them via jquery, best by splitting headings and value columns in two different divs, and just updating the headings once on start, and the value columns whenever needed via JSON call and JQUERY.

Comment: I'm re-writing using the getJson method. I have the php code written and now playing around with getJson.